# Ajuda com LINQ, query no .Net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-sql

Bom dia, pessoal, estou precisando de uma ajuda com LINQ.
Estou tentando realizar a seguinte query através do linq:

```
SELECT NFE_SAIDA.NFESAI_SEQUENCIA   
       FROM CAD_NFE_SAIDA NFE_SAIDA  
LEFT JOIN CAD_NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES ON NFE_SAIDA.NFESAI_SEQUENCIA = NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES.NFESAI_SEQUENCIA AND 
NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES.EST_SEQUENCIA = 2 AND
NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES.NFESAIEST_SINCRONIZADO = 'S'
WHERE NFE_SAIDA.EMP_SEQUENCIA = 1
AND NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES.NFESAIEST_SEQUENCIA IS NULL
```

No resumo, Preciso de todos os itens da tabela `A(CAD_NFE_SAIDA)` quando seu `LEFT` com a tabela `B(CAD_NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES) (Da EST_SEQUENCIA = 2 , e SINCRONIZADOS = 'S')`
não esteja satisfeito.
Assim, pegarei o ID de todas as notas que ainda não foram sincronizados naquela estação.

---

Tentei da seguinte forma :

```
var query = (from _NFESAIDA in _contexto.NfeSaida.Where(_C => _C.EmpSequencia == empSequencia)
join _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO in _contexto.NfeSaidaEstacao on _NFESAIDA.NfesaiSequencia equals _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO.NfesaiSequencia into _a
from _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO in _a.DefaultIfEmpty()
.Where(_A => _A.NfesaiSincronizado != "S").DefaultIfEmpty().Where(_A => _A.EstSequencia == estSequencia).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ObjSequenciaNota {
Sequencia = _NFESAIDA.NfesaiSequencia}
);  
return query;
```

Porem, o linq faz um INNER join com a tabela 'B' oque invalida minha consulta.
Algum help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
var queryLeft = from x in _contexto.NfeSaidaEstacao.Where(_C => _C.EstSequencia == estSequencia && _C.NfesaiSincronizada == "S") select x;

var query = from x in _contexto.NfeSaida.Where(_C => _C.EmpSequencia == empSequencia)
                        join z in queryLeft on x.NfesaiSequencia equals z.NfesaiSequencia into j1
                        from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where j2 == null
                        select (new ObjSequenciaNota { Sequencia = x.NfesaiSequencia});

return query;
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar o linq da seguinte forma.

```
var query = (from _NFESAIDA in _contexto.NfeSaida
             join _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO in _contexto.NfeSaidaEstacao on _NFESAIDA.NfesaiSequencia equals _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO.NfesaiSequencia into _a from _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO in _a.DefaultIfEmpty()

             where _NFESAIDA.EmpSequencia == empSequencia &&
             _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO.NfesaiSincronizado == "S" &&
             _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO.EstSequencia == estSequencia &&
             _NFESAIDA_ESTACAO.NFESAIEST_SEQUENCIA  == null /// AND NFE_SAIDA_ESTACOES.NFESAIEST_SEQUENCIA IS NULL

             select new ObjSequenciaNota
             {
                 Sequencia = _NFESAIDA.NfesaiSequencia
             }
);
```

Primeiro faça o seu Left Join com sua tabela NfeSaidaEstacao o DefaultIfEmpty é o que faz a query tornar Left, e só depois faça seus Where ... e Ands.

Veja a coluna NFESAIEST_SEQUENCIA como esta no seu modelo.

Você pode mudar a query para primeiro pegar os dados da tabela NfeSaida fazer os filtro dela e depois fazer um NOT EXISTS com sua tabela NfeSaidaEstacao, veja ´exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031070/2740371)