# LINQ com JOIN e cláusula where, como fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando fazer um `left outer join (SQL)` com o LINQ, porém, não estou conseguindo.

O código da minha classe, é este abaixo. Alguem consegue me dar uma luz de como resolvo isso?

```
public class PessoaController : Controller
{
    // GET: Pessoa
    public ActionResult Index(string _nome )
    {
        Entities banco = new Entities();

        List<PESSOASFJ> listapessoa = (from pes in banco.PESSOASFJ
            join nf in banco.NOTAFISCALCAPA on pes.IDPESSOAFJ equals nf.PESSOASFJ into GrupoNF
            from b in GrupoNF
            Where(p => p.Contains(_nome.ToUpper())) select pes).ToList();

        return View(listapessoa);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria um `LEFT JOIN`de PESSOASFJ com NOTAFISCALCAPA  ?

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar LEFT JOIN utilizando Linq você precisa usar a Instrução **DefaultIfEmpty**.

> A instrução **DefaultIfEmpty** é utilizada para evitar erros em
>   coleções vazias substituindo por um valor padrão que pode ser
>   atribuído ou não conforme sua
>   necessidade.

Portanto, esta instrução atende a sua necessidade onde você pode atribuir a instrução DefaultIfEmpty na entidade em que deseja realizar LEFT JOIN. ;)

Segue um exemplo abaixo no dotnetfiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nhMzK

Answer (score 1):

```
using(Entities banco = new Entities())
{

    List<PESSOASFJ> listapessoa = (from pes in banco.PESSOASFJ
        join nf in banco.NOTAFISCALCAPA on pes.IDPESSOAFJ equals nf.PESSOASFJ into GrupoNF
        from b in GrupoNF.DefaultIfEmpty()
        Where(p => p.Contains(_nome.ToUpper())) 
        select pes
        ).ToList();

    return View(listapessoa);
}
```

Veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/265868/43340).

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi dito em outra resposta, para realizar o `LEFT JOIN` você precisará usar a Instrução [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx).

Segue abaixo o trecho de código:

```
public class PessoaController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(string _nome )
   {
     Entities banco = new Entities();
     List<PESSOASFJ> listapessoa = (
       from pes in banco.PESSOASFJ.Where(p => p.Contains(_nome.ToUpper()))
       from nf in banco.NOTAFISCALCAPA.Where(o => o.PESSOASFJ == pes.IDPESSOAFJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
       select pes ).ToList();

     return View(listapessoa);
   }
}
```